# PHP AND Statement

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have some code for a plugin that is doing an AND statement to work out the data['type'] and then use that in a switch statement as follows;

```
    foreach($coupons as $coupon)
    {
        $data = $this->_get_coupon_code_data($coupon);

        if(empty($data)) continue;
        //if($data['type'] != 'Cartthrob_discount_amount_off_product' AND $data['type'] != 'Cartthrob_discount_percentage_off') continue;
        if($data['type'] != 'Cartthrob_discount_percentage_off_product' AND $data['type'] != 'Cartthrob_discount_percentage_off') continue;

        switch($data['type']) {
            case 'Cartthrob_discount_amount_off_product' :
                // Is this coupon applied to this item?
                $coupon_entry_ids = explode(',', $data['entry_ids']);
                if(in_array($row['id'], $coupon_entry_ids))
                {
                    // Valid and applied to this product
                    $discount_applied = $discount_applied + $data['amount_off'];
                }
            break;

            // Percentage Off a Single Product
            case 'Cartthrob_discount_percentage_off_product' :
              $percentage_off = $data['percentage_off'];
                $discount = 0;
                // Is this coupon applied to this item?
                $coupon_entry_ids = explode(',', $data['entry_ids']);
                if(in_array($row['id'], $coupon_entry_ids))
                {
                    // Valid and applied to this product
                    //$discount = round($row['id'] * ( $data['percentage_off'] / 100 ), 2, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);
                    $discount = round($row['price_before_tax'] * ( $data['percentage_off'] / 100 ), 2, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);
                    $discount_applied = $discount_applied + $discount;
                }
            break;

            case 'Cartthrob_discount_percentage_off' :

                $percentage_off = $data['percentage_off'];
                $discount = 0;
                // discounts are calculated against pre tax price
                $discount = round($row['price_before_tax'] * ( $data['percentage_off'] / 100 ), 2, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);

                $discount_applied = $discount_applied + $discount;

            break;
        }

    }
```

This is working fine, but i need to add a check for two further data['type]'s with that first line. I'm wondering if someone could help me change it so that I can add in a check for all of the following data types;

> - Cartthrob_discount_amount_off_product
> - Cartthrob_discount_percentage_off
> - Cartthrob_discount_percentage_off_product
> - Cartthrob_discount_amount_off_over_x

When I added these in the first conditional statement with multiple AND's it obviously failed.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the issue, your code all ready handles multiple cases, why not just add the new types to it?

Comment: I don't see any sense in that first conditional at all. Since `$data['type']` certainly can only have a single static value in each run the `switch` statement by itself is sufficient.

Comment: For some reason there is a case written for Cartthrob_discount_percentage_off_product and Cartthrob_discount_percentage_off_product is in that initial IF statement. He probably needs to comment out the case if he's removing that IF? Same for Cartthrob_discount_percentage_off... actually, this code just boggles me.

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` statement raises a `continue` when is `true`, so if your data type is equal  "Cartthrob_discount_percentage_off_product" or "Cartthrob_discount_percentage_off", the rest of your code will not run (I'm considering that this code is inside a looping).

Firstly, if you want to ignore this two specific cases, use a `OR` rather than `AND`, since the `data['type']` just have one value per time, so:

```
if($data['type'] != 'Cartthrob_discount_percentage_off_product' OR $data['type'] != 'Cartthrob_discount_percentage_off') continue;
```

However, apparently, you don't want it, 'cause you want a condition for each possible value of `data['type']`, so, just ignore the `if` and change your `switch` statement to

```
switch($data['type']) {
        case 'Cartthrob_discount_amount_off_product' :
            // Is this coupon applied to this item?
            $coupon_entry_ids = explode(',', $data['entry_ids']);
            if(in_array($row['id'], $coupon_entry_ids))
            {
                // Valid and applied to this product
                $discount_applied = $discount_applied + $data['amount_off'];
            }
        break;

        // Percentage Off a Single Product
        case 'Cartthrob_discount_percentage_off_product' :
          $percentage_off = $data['percentage_off'];
            $discount = 0;
            // Is this coupon applied to this item?
            $coupon_entry_ids = explode(',', $data['entry_ids']);
            if(in_array($row['id'], $coupon_entry_ids))
            {
                // Valid and applied to this product
                //$discount = round($row['id'] * ( $data['percentage_off'] / 100 ), 2, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);
                $discount = round($row['price_before_tax'] * ( $data['percentage_off'] / 100 ), 2, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);
                $discount_applied = $discount_applied + $discount;
            }
        break;

        case 'Cartthrob_discount_percentage_off' :

            $percentage_off = $data['percentage_off'];
            $discount = 0;
            // discounts are calculated against pre tax price
            $discount = round($row['price_before_tax'] * ( $data['percentage_off'] / 100 ), 2, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);

            $discount_applied = $discount_applied + $discount;

        break;
        case 'Cartthrob_discount_amount_off_over_x' :

            //do stuff for this case

        break;
    }
```

**UPDATE**

I don't know if I understood your problem at all, but here are some options that I believe that could be helpful to you.

The variable `$data['type']` just has one value per iteration of `foreach`.
So, the `if` statement with `AND` still looks useless to me.

See, if you want to ignore the "Cartthrob_discount_percentage_off_product" and "Cartthrob_discount_percentage_off" values, you could use the `if` with OR as I said before.

On the other hand, if you want consider all the possibilities (being 4 or 15, it don't matter), you just need to ignore the if and include all the possibilities inside of `switch`, one per case.

Maybe, you are using the `continue` in the wrong way. Here are the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php). When your if statement is true, the rest of your code inside of `foreach` is ignored and the next instruction is to go to next iteration.

If you want to ensure that your switch just will be execute for "Cartthrob_discount_percentage_off_product" and "Cartthrob_discount_percentage_off" values, you can do:

```
if($data['type'] != 'Cartthrob_discount_percentage_off_product' AND $data['type'] != 'Cartthrob_discount_percentage_off') {
    //erase continue and put your switch inside of the if statement
    switch($data['type']) {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

Although this code does not make much sense because the switch already works like a if in this case, could be what you want.

Comment: Hi James, I have updated the code for clarity (hopefully). It's someone else's code that I'm trying to adapt to cover more cases. There's basically about 15 different data types (in this project they are discount methods). The code above is for a report and we only care about the 4 discount methods mentioned above so I think this was why there was the initial statement when there were only 2 methods to check.

Comment: @doubleplusgood I don't know if I understood your problem yet, but see my update. Hope it helps.